# Trouble understanding pseudo code for deleting a node with two children

Tags: binary-search-tree, nodes, pseudocode

I'm trying to understand the algorithm for deleting a node with two children a little more.  My teacher wrote pseudo code for us to learn but I'm having a hard time understanding certain aspects of it.

let's assume so far that I have already found the node i need to delete, so i have the current and node in the right place.

```
temp = current 
tempParent = temp
temp = temp.right

while(temp.left != null)
     tempParent = temp
     temp = temp.left


{  //this is where i begin to get confused
    tempParent.left = temp.right
    temp.left = current.left                   
    temp.right = current.right
   // if we traversed until temp.left == null, how could  there be a temp.left?       
}  // end confusion

// I understand this if statement right here
if current == parent.left
     parent.left = temp
else
     parent.right = temp
```

thanks guys

Comment: Can you re-indent the code to match what you were given?

Comment: if you're asking to indent it the way she wrote it, that's how it was indented lol could be why i'm confused

Comment: @TheoretiCAL but I will reindent it to how i think it was meant to be

Comment: @TheoretiCAL Right, I understand that the while loop finds the left most element, but what I'm confused about is directly under the traversal.  The part that is tempParent.left = temp.right and under, i just have a hard time visualizing it.